# Django-registration: How to allow user delete their account?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have a simple website where users can register in order to have access to private content and to receive a newsletter. I have used [django-registration](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.2) for user registration and authentication, and  used some HTML templates from [here](https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates/tree/master/registration).

The whole system is working (login, logout, password recovery, etc.) but I realized that user cannot delete their account from the website. Is there a plugin designed for this, or how to extend the registration classes to do that? By deleting, I'd prefer a real suppression, not just making the user inactive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}
    
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
        u.delete()
        context['msg'] = 'The user is deleted.'       
    except User.DoesNotExist: 
        context['msg'] = 'User does not exist.'
    except Exception as e: 
        context['msg'] = e.message

    return render(request, 'template.html', context=context)
```

And have a url pattern like:

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<username>[\w|\W.-]+)/$', views.delete_user, name='delete-user')
```

This will do the work. It will delete a user by given username.

**But**, as [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) say:

> `is_active`
>
> Boolean. Designates whether this user account should be considered active. **We recommend that you set this flag to `False` instead of deleting accounts**; that way, if your applications have any foreign keys to users, the foreign keys won’t break.

It is a better approach to set the user as *inactive* instead of deleting it totally from the database, because the foreign keys will break.

So you can simply do:

```
def delete_user(request, username):
    context = {}

    try:
        user = User.object.get(username=username)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        context['msg'] = 'Profile successfully disabled.'
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        # ...
    except Exception as e:
        # ...
    
    # ...
```

And as now everyone can access this view, you must add some permissions. A straightforward approach will be to override the built-in `@user_passes_test` decorator:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url=reverse_lazy('login'))
def delete_user(request, username):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Your answer is very instructive

Answer (score 0):

I used the DeleteView class to solve a similar problem.
The code below allows registered users without administrative
privilege to the Django admin site, to delete their own accounts
after login.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import DeleteView

User = get_user_model()

class UserDelete(DeleteView):
    model = User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'user_confirm_delete.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserDelete

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/delete', UserDelete.as_view(), name='user_confirm_delete'),
]
```

templates/user_confirm_delete.html

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load account %}

{% block title %}User Account Delete{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete your account?</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>
    {% else %}
        <p><a href="#">Login</a></p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

templates/_base.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'user_confirm_delete' user.id %}">Delete Account</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="#">Log In</a>
{% endif %}
```

Django 3.1 Documentation:
[Generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that if I had the PK of a user I could delete their account?