# Django: let user delete own User instance from default model User

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model `Creator` which is linked to the Django standard `User` model via a `OneToOneField` field. The `Creator` model is there to allow me more flexibility when adding/editing information of a `Creator`. Now for deleting a `Creator` I use the generic `DeleteView`. However, this does not delete the `User` instance and hence is not completely what I am looking to do (e.g. the username of the deleted `Creator` is "already taken"). **Is there a way to use the default `DeleteView` to let a user delete his account?** What is the best practice to do a "delete account" operation regarding deleting the `User` instance, logging out the user, and confirming the success of the operation?

What I tried so far:

**models.py**

```
class Creator(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    street_and_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super(Creator, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('creator-detail', args=[str(self.slug)])
```

**views.py**

```
class CreatorDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    #model = User # does not work
    model = Creator
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    # these two methods only give access to the users own profile but not the others
    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())
        return super(CreatorDelete, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('creator/<slug:slug>/delete/', views.CreatorDelete.as_view(), name='creator-delete')
```

Also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780470/django-registration-how-to-allow-user-delete-their-account) seemed quiet promising, but since I would like to use a `user_confirm_delete.html` template and rather a class based view (to implement a check that a user can only delete his own account) I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: You could use `model = User` and override `get_object()` (when you delete the `User`, the linked `Creator` will also be deleted because of the `on_delete` cascade). Then you could keep the slug out of the URL entirely, which avoids the test, and might end up as less code overall. Also, unless you have users who aren't creators, you can define a custom user model in Django and avoid having two models.

Comment: I figured it out using the answer below. But it was crucial to note the ```CASCADE``` parameter, as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`delete()`** method as,

```
class CreatorDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    .....
    .....
    .....

    # your code

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        self.object.user.delete()  # deleting the default "User" model
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Comment: as can be seen from the admin page, this does delete the ```Creator``` instance but not the ```User``` instance. I figured I can leave out the line ```response = super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)``` since my ```Creator``` model specifies ```CASCADE``` when the ```User``` instance is deleted. Resulting I changed the ```return``` statement as well. After all it does work as wanted, thank you :)